# Button changes function after clicking a link

Tags: javascript, button, navigation

I have a navigation buttons based on a list, with javascript.

Everything works fine, but when clicking a button link, the function gets broken...

What's the problem??? Any help will be great!! Thanks.

```js
$(".FIRST").click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('active')){
        $(this).removeClass('active')
 } else {
        $(this).addClass('active')
    }
});

$(".FIRST").click(function (evt) {      
        if(evt.target.tagName != 'UL') 
            return;
        $("li", this).toggle();
    });
```

```css
ul li {list-style: none;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

a {text-decoration: none; color: white;}

.FIRST {
    font-size:0px;
    width: 1px;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: green;
    border: solid 1px red;
}

.FIRST:hover {background-color: lightgreen;}

.FIRST.active {background-color: yellow;}

.SECOND {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius:12px;
    background-color: green;
    line-height:30px;
    margin: 0 auto 6px 55px;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    padding: 0 10px 0 20px;
}

.FIRST:hover {background-color: lightgreen;}

.FIRST.active {background-color: yellow;}
.SECOND:hover {background-color: lightgreen;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="FIRST" id="MAIN">
    <li class="SECOND">
        <a href="http://blank.org/" target="_blank">
           LINK 1
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="SECOND">
        <a href="http://blank.org/" target="_blank">
            LINK 2
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="SECOND">
        <a href="http://blank.org/" target="_blank">
            LINK 3
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="SECOND">
        <a href="http://blank.org/" target="_blank">
            LINK 4
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/danielillo/v6hhu9b0/)

Thanks

Comment: you mean the square box a/k 'button' changes to yellow when clicking a link?

Comment: No, after clicking a link, when i pass the mouse over the links affect the hover of the ( ul )  button.

Comment: It affects the hover of the <ul> button meaning? it affects a change in color...what is the behaviour of the ul tag you do not want when you hover over the links.....:)

Comment: ok, clicking the button, gets active (yellow), the links are visible. After clicking a link, going back to the fiddle, when the mouse is over the links buttons, the yellow button is not active (yellow), is green and when the mouse is over the links, the original button change the color to it hover color, lightgreen.

Comment: I was away for a while...okay...My answer posted since the question is a little clearer...

Answer (score 0):

Try addding a judgment in the first Function

```
$(".FIRST").click(function() {
    if (evt.target.tagName != 'UL')
    return;
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});});
```

ps:I think you should put the button as a separate tag

Answer (score 0):

Your anchors are in `<li>` tags which is also a child of your `<ul>` with class '.FIRST' hence.

Whenever you click on the anchor links the event is also captured by your parent container, that is `<ul>` with class `.FIRST`.

In this case your parent container is your `<ul>` which a click handler is attached. Hence when you click on any of the anchors, it triggers `jquery toggle()` function which changes the color of your `<ul>` with class `.FIRST`.

**An easier approach would be**

make button button by using a div container and attach a click handler to it. This click handler will cause the div to change its color and also toggle the list to show or hide.

**SNIPPET HERE**

```js
$(".FIRST").click(function(){
if($('#big_list').css('opacity')=='0'){
 $('#big_list').css('opacity','1');
 }
else{
$('#big_list').css('opacity','0');
}
    if($(this).hasClass('active')){
        $(this).removeClass('active')
        
 } else {
        $(this).addClass('active'); 
    }
});
```

```css
ul li {list-style: none;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

a {text-decoration: none; color: white;}

.FIRST {
   vertical-align:top;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relatve;
  top:0;
    font-size:0px;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: green;
    border: solid 1px red;
}



#big_list{
  display:inline-block;
  opacity:0;
  margin:auto;
  padding:0;
}
#container{
  position:relative;
  top:0px;

}

.SECOND {
    width: 120px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius:12px;
    background-color: green;
    margin: 0 auto 6px 0px;
    font-size:12px;
    padding: 0 10px 0 20px;
}


.FIRST.active {background-color: yellow;}
.SECOND:hover {background-color: lightgreen;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='container'>
<div class="FIRST" id="MAIN">
</div>
<ul id='big_list'>
    <li class="SECOND">
        <a href="http://blank.org/" target="_blank">
           LINK 1
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="SECOND">
        <a href="http://blank.org/" target="_blank">
            LINK 2
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="SECOND">
        <a href="http://blank.org/" target="_blank">
            LINK 3
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="SECOND">
        <a href="http://blank.org/" target="_blank">
            LINK 4
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, as far as i see works perfect. I will take a look.